# What the relationship of least square and X'Xθ = X'y?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra, linear-regression, least-squares

I have three points: (1,1), (2,3), (3, 3.123). I assume the hypothesis is [image], and I want to do linear regression on the three points. I have two methods to calculate θ:

### Method-1: Least Square

```python
import numpy as np
# get an approximate solution using least square
X = np.array([[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]])
y = np.array([1,3,3.123])
theta = np.linalg.lstsq(X,y)[0]
print theta
```

### Method-2: Matrix multiplication

We have the following derivation process:

[image]

```python
# rank(X)=2, rank(X|y)=3, so there is no exact solution.
print np.linalg.matrix_rank(X)
print np.linalg.matrix_rank(np.c_[X,y])
theta = np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T.dot(y))
print theta
```

Both method-1 and method-2 can get result `[ 1.0615      0.25133333]`, it seems that method-2 is equivalent to least square. But, I don't know why, can anyone reveal the underlying principle of their equivalence?

Comment: Here is a good explationation: [Solution of Least Square](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx69N5pLghi8QkRiYTQwa2hTZEE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are equivalent, because least squares method is 
 θ = argmin (Xθ-Y)'(Xθ-Y) = argmin ||(Xθ-Y)||^2 = argmin ||(Xθ-Y)||, that means that you try to minimize length of vector (Xθ-Y), so you try to minimize distance between Xθ and Y. X is a constant matrix, so Xθ is vector from column space of X. That means the shortest distance between these two vectors is when Xθ is equal to projection of vector Y to column space of X (can be easy observed from picture). That results to Y^(hat) = Xθ = X(X'X)^(-1)X'Y, where X(X'X)^(-1)X' is the projection matrix to column space of X. After some changes you can observe that this is equivalent with (X'X)θ = X'Y. You can find exact proof in any linear algebra book.